# void draw function in processing language

Tags: processing

Is it possible to write a `void draw()` function inside an `if()` function?
I have tried writing a program where if the mouse is clicked, the `draw()` should draw me the output. processing displays an error that points at the `if()`

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] showing what you've tried?

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and add problematic part of your code. Also please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You've to provide the code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

you can't run an `if()` outside of the draw, so long answer short: no.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw something while the mouse is being pressed, you have infinite choices to take. I'd suggest looking at the [`mousePressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html) and [`mouseReleased()`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseReleased_.html) functions, which you are supposed to override:

```java
void setup() {
  size(500,500);
}

void draw() {
 // nothing is being drawn here, we'll draw from
 // mousePressed at the end of every frame
}

void mousePressed() {
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(width/2,width/2,100,100);
}
```

You can use `mousePressed()` to make other pieces of your code know that they are supposed to do something, and get them ready for the next frame in `draw()`. Drawing from it is generally not a good idea.

There's the `mousePressed` variable too, which equals `true` until the mouse is released:

```java
void setup() {
  size(500,500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
 if (mousePressed) {
   rectMode(CENTER);
   rect(width/2,width/2,100,100);
   // if the mouse is released, this code
   // won't be executed, so the background
   // is the only thing that's going to be
   // drawn in that frame
 }
}
```